# Can you still fly under the exemption for recreational flyers after obtaining a remote pilot certificate?

Tags: faa

I have two drones. One has a camera, and I might use it commercially at some point. It could carry a Remote ID transmitter. The other does not have a camera, and has no use other than recreational flight. It's way too small to carry any "cargo." If I get a remote pilot certificate to be able to fly under Part 107, can I still fly the unregistered drone under the exemption for recreational flyers after Remote ID rules take effect?

Comment: Does one actually register drones in USA? In Europe the operator is registered and mark their drones. I would be very surprised if you couldn't do what you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If you hold an FAA Part 107 license, and you are not flying in a manner that requires a 107 license, you are free to fly as a recreational pilot.  See here:  https://www.faa.gov/uas/recreational_flyers

Comment: Yes (asterisk), subject to weight requirements etc.